# Оформление эпиграфа

Tags: оформление-текста

Добрый вечер! Очень прошу помочь с оформлением эпиграфа.

Homo homini lupus est                                                                     
(Человек человеку волк)

В эпиграфе текст по-латыни написан на одной строке, а перевод на другой. Именно интересует, нужно ли текст на русском брать в кавычки и менять Ч на ч.

Comment: по - латынИ

Comment: По-латыни!

Answer (score 5):

Печатный текст или от руки?

Если печатный - правила таковы:

Эпиграфы всегда верстают на суженный формат (от ⅓ до ⅔ формата строки основного набора) шрифтом меньшего кегля, часто выделительным, например, курсивом. Если в эпиграфе дается иностранный текст с переводом, то их верстают разными начертаниями шрифта (часто основной текст — курсивом, а перевод — прямым), причем перевод отбивают на 4–8 п. В конце эпиграфа ставят точку или иной, необходимый по смыслу знак (весьма часто — многоточие, ибо текст цитаты обрывается). В кавычки текст эпиграфа не заключают. Почти всегда имеется ссылка на источник; ее набирают отдельной строкой с выделением шрифтом без точки на конце и с отбивкой от текста эпиграфа на 2–4 п.

Homo homini lupus est.

Человек человеку волк.

Тит Макций Плавт

Comment: Текст печатный, Людмила, спасибо!